# Symfony2 + GuzzleHTTP - How to properly set a json response

Tags: json, api, symfony, guzzle

I'm building APIs for an application in Symfony2. I'm using also Guzzle for testing. 
I want to return as a response a list of users in JSON format. This is how I'm doing that. 
First I create the function, where I retrieve all the users from the db. Then I use the JMSSerializerBundle to serialize the data in JSON.

```
//APIController.php    

/**
 * @Route("/api/showUsers")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function showUsersAction() 
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Users');
    $users = $repository->findAll();
    $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
    $response = $serializer->serialize($users,'json');

    return new Response ($response, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
}
```

Then I have a `testing.php` file inside my project where I'm testing the result with Guzzle.

```
//testing.php    

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_url' => 'http://localhost:83/',
    'defaults' => [
        'exceptions' => false
    ],
]);

$response = $client->get('api/showUsers');
echo $response;
```

Now, when I launch `php testing.php` in my terminal I get the 200 status code, but `text/html` as **Content-Type**. So what I see as a response is the full html code.
Instead, when I launch the function from the browser, I get the response in the JSON format.

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Which version of Guzzle do you use?

Comment: @Roukmoute I use the 5

Comment: You may always return JsonResponse: http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.html

Comment: @barat I've tried also with JsonResponse. This is just a test. Thanks

Comment: Have You tried it like this?

$response = new Response({'jsonhere'});
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response;

Comment: @barat It worked! But instead of $response = new Response({'jsonhere'}); I had to write $response = new Response(json_encode('jsonhere')); Thanks!

Comment: It's how it's done in JsonResponse - sometimes it's worth to look into built-in classes :)